# JavaScript losing focus on edit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a table where when the user clicks on a value, to allow the user to edit the entry without having to go to a different area with HTML and JavaScript. I got basically everything I need, except I don't know why the focus keeps disappearing when clicking in the textbox/dropdown.

Could someone help me out here?

```
    function valid_number() {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function getID(oObject, type, objname) {
        var id_fetched = oObject.id;
        var visit_id;
        var var_name;
        var old_value;
        var type;
        var objname;

        raw_values = id_fetched.split("|");
        visit_id = raw_values[0];
        var_name = raw_values[1];
        old_value = raw_values[2];
        var edit_id = document.getElementById("edit_id").value;
        var reason_for_change = document.getElementById("reason").value;

        //has the reason been filled out?
        if (reason_for_change === "") {
            alert('Cannot edit yet, must fill out reason for edit first!');
        } else {
            //reason given, proceed with edit

            if (type === "text") {
                document.getElementById(id_fetched).innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + objname + "' value='" + old_value + "' />";
            };

            if (type === "numeric") {
                document.getElementById(id_fetched).innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + objname + "' value='" + old_value + "' onkeypress=\"return valid_number(event)\" />";
            };

            if (type === "yes_no") {
                document.getElementById(id_fetched).innerHTML = "<select name='" + objname + "'><option value='0'>NO</option><option value='1'>YES</option></select>";
            };

            if (type === "yes_no_opt") {
                document.getElementById(id_fetched).innerHTML = "<select name='" + objname + "'><option value='0'>NO</option><option value='1'>OPT</option><option value='2'>REQ</option></select>";
            };


        }
    }
</script>
```

Then the table is:

```
<form method="GET">
    <table id="visit_table" name="visit_table" border="1">
        <tr><td colspan="14">Reason for change: <input type="text" id="reason" name="reason" length="225" maxlength="330" value="test" /> <input type="hidden" id="edit_id" name="edit_id" value="cf36903986716bc51f7e0b026c5a189e" /></td></tr><tr><th>Order</th><th>Name</th><th>BL</th><th>SCR</th><th>rSCR</th><th>RAND</th><th>PH.VIS.</th><th>UNSCHED</th><th>Sched.Only</th><th>REVENUE</th><th>COUNT</th><th>PROJ.VIS</th><th>STIPEND</th><th>ACTIVE</th></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5054|visit_order|1.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5054-visitorder');">1.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5054|visit_name|Visit 1 Wk 0             " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5054-visitname');">Visit 1 Wk 0             </td><td contenteditable id="5054|baseline_visit|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-blvisit');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5054|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5054-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5054|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5054|randomization_visit|2" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5054-randvisit');">REQ</td><td contenteditable id="5054|phone_visit| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5054|unsched_visit| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5054|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5054|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5054|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5054|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5054|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5054-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5054|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5054-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5055|visit_order|2.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5055-visitorder');">2.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5055|visit_name|Visit 2 Wk 2             " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5055-visitname');">Visit 2 Wk 2             </td><td contenteditable id="5055|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5055|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5055-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5055|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5055|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5055-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5055|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5055|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5055|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5055|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5055|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5055|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5055|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5055-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5055|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5055-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5056|visit_order|3.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5056-visitorder');">3.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5056|visit_name|Visit 3 Wk 4             " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5056-visitname');">Visit 3 Wk 4             </td><td contenteditable id="5056|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5056|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5056-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5056|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5056|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5056-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5056|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5056|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5056|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5056|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5056|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5056|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5056|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5056-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5056|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5056-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5057|visit_order|4.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5057-visitorder');">4.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5057|visit_name|Visit 4 Wk 6             " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5057-visitname');">Visit 4 Wk 6             </td><td contenteditable id="5057|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5057|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5057-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5057|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5057|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5057-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5057|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5057|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5057|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5057|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5057|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5057|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5057|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5057-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5057|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5057-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5058|visit_order|5.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5058-visitorder');">5.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5058|visit_name|Visit 5 Wk 12            " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5058-visitname');">Visit 5 Wk 12            </td><td contenteditable id="5058|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5058|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5058-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5058|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5058|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5058-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5058|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5058|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5058|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5058|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5058|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5058|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5058|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5058-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5058|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5058-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5059|visit_order|6.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5059-visitorder');">6.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5059|visit_name|Visit 5A Wk 18           " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5059-visitname');">Visit 5A Wk 18           </td><td contenteditable id="5059|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5059|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5059-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5059|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5059|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5059-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5059|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5059|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5059|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5059|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5059|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5059|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5059|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5059-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5059|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5059-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5060|visit_order|7.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5060-visitorder');">7.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5060|visit_name|Visit 6 Wk 24            " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5060-visitname');">Visit 6 Wk 24            </td><td contenteditable id="5060|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5060|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5060-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5060|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5060|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5060-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5060|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5060|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5060|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5060|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5060|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5060|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5060|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5060-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5060|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5060-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5061|visit_order|8.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5061-visitorder');">8.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5061|visit_name|Visit 6A Wk 30           " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5061-visitname');">Visit 6A Wk 30           </td><td contenteditable id="5061|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5061|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5061-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5061|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5061|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5061-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5061|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5061|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5061|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5061|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5061|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5061|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5061|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5061-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5061|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5061-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5062|visit_order|9.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5062-visitorder');">9.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5062|visit_name|Visit 7 Wk 36            " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5062-visitname');">Visit 7 Wk 36            </td><td contenteditable id="5062|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5062|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5062-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5062|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5062|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5062-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5062|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5062|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5062|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5062|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5062|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5062|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5062|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5062-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5062|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5062-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5063|visit_order|10.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5063-visitorder');">10.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5063|visit_name|Visit 7A Wk 42           " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5063-visitname');">Visit 7A Wk 42           </td><td contenteditable id="5063|baseline_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5063|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5063-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5063|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5063|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5063-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5063|phone_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5063|unsched_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5063|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5063|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5063|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5063|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5063|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5063-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5063|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5063-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5064|visit_order|11.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5064-visitorder');">11.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5064|visit_name|Visit 8/Wk 48 Final/ET   " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5064-visitname');">Visit 8/Wk 48 Final/ET   </td><td contenteditable id="5064|baseline_visit| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5064|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5064-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5064|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5064|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5064-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5064|phone_visit| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5064|unsched_visit| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-unschedvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5064|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5064|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5064|count_vis|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-countvis');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5064|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5064|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5064-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5064|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5064-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable id="5065|visit_order|12.0000" onclick="getID(this, 'numeric', '5065-visitorder');">12.0000</td><td contenteditable id="5065|visit_name|Unscheduled              " onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5065-visitname');">Unscheduled              </td><td contenteditable id="5065|baseline_visit| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-blvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5065|screening_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5065-scrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5065|rescr_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-rescrvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5065|randomization_visit|0" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no_opt', '5065-randvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5065|phone_visit| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-phvisit');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5065|unsched_visit|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-unschedvisit');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5065|sched_only_visit|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-schedonly');">&nbsp;</td><td contenteditable id="5065|count_rev|1" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-countrev');">YES</td><td contenteditable id="5065|count_vis| " onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-countvis');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5065|proj_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-projvisit');">NO</td><td contenteditable id="5065|patient_stipend|0.00" onclick="getID(this, 'text', '5065-stipend');">0.00</td><td contenteditable id="5065|active_vis|" onclick="getID(this, 'yes_no', '5065-active');">NO</td></tr><tr><td colspan="14" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Make Changes"></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Notice, that `td` doesn't support `contenteditable` in IEs.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing focus because you are not removing the "onclick" listener from the cell. It basically adds a new input each time you click on it or on the dropdown list.

Try adding

```
oObject.onclick = null;
```

Somewhere in the "getID" code.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n34joy3m/)